# php glob() not finding any files

Tags: php, glob

```
$directory = $_SESSION['base_url'] . "assets/images/*.jpg";
$images = glob($directory);
```

This code is not working. If I print out $directory, it matches the directory where I have put some .jpg files. $images just remains empty...

As **bsdnoobz** answered, this was my solution:

```
$directory = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "\assets\images\\"; //escape
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `$_SESSION['base_url']` points to your app's URL (like `http://example.com`). You should use filesystem path instead of URL. Try something like this:

```
$directory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/assets/images/*.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$directory = $_SESSION['base_url'] . "assets/images/*.jpg";
$images = glob($directory);
```

There was an additional `'`.

Comment: That's actually just a typo in the question. Edited it, as i said: I printed out the directory, which is correct...

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `'` between the `/` and the `.jpg`